# How to overlap a base map with a png map (format .pgn) on QGIS-Pisa?

Tags: qgis, overlay, overlapping-features

How can I overlap a relief base map taken from maps-for-free.com [image] and this png-formated map [image] so that I can get a resulting map with relief of the 1st map and boundaries of the 2nd map ?? I'm a beginner. I don't know if QGIS has any functionality like that ? I use QGIS version 2.10.1-Pisa and my operating system is Windows 7 x64bit.

Comment: Why there's no one answers my question ? does this functionality not exist in QGIS ??

Comment: It seems to me that you are really trying to get a full tutorial for your task from stackexchange users. Come on, thats really not how things should work here. Most people first try to learn basics by reading, and then dare to ask such questions when they are stuck. You seem to have been stuck at level zero!

Comment: By "boundaries" do you mean the thick solid lines **and** the dashed lines, but not the rivers, labels, grey circles, town locations, annotations etc? You will have to do this manually. In the old days we had a huge map digitising table for this sort of thing but now you can do it on-screen as described below.

Comment: @Spaceman, Yes, that's what I mean by "boundaries" (the thick lines, dashed lines).

Comment: @Bernd V, What did you say to me ? are you a troll or something ? I have problem with technical steps and just need some help here.

Answer (score 3):

1. [Here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/167889/how-can-i-add-map-from-website-maps-for-free-com-as-my-base-map-on-qgis-2-10-1-p/167895#167895) you were thoroughly answered on how to add your basemap (first map) in QGIS
2. What you need to do next is called georeferencing.

   - Go to plugins and make sure that Georeferencer GDAL is on
   - menu Raster\Georeferencer
   - add your second map
   - add at least 6 points from your second map getting coordinates for each from your first map (also feel free to add more basemaps if the first one is not enough)
3. Create new vector layer (lines or polygons depending on what you need in the end).
   Layer\Create Layer\New shapefile
4. Digitize boundaries from the second map.

Digitizing and georeferencing are covered in [QGIS Manual](http://www.qgis.org/en/docs/index.html).

Comment: If you edited the image in Photoshop or Gimp (or MSPaint) and cleaned out all the annotation, and joined up the dotted line boundaries, would an automated raster->vector conversion work? The image probably needs a lot of editing though. And its nearly always easier to find a shapefile of the boundaries you want anyway...

Comment: @Spacedman, I bet this would take 2x more time in this particular case ;)