# Adding map from maps-for-free to QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-openlayers-plugin, basemap, quickmapservices

I've already tried [How can I add map from website maps-for-free.com as my base map on QGIS 2.10.1-Pisa?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/167889) with the adjusted filepath for the metadata.ini file but it didn't work. The FreeMap option doesn't show up in the dropdown menu.

Am I missing something or is this service not available anymore for QGS 3.4?

Comment: forgot to add the error I get: "Couldn't load plugin 'quick_map_services' due to an error when calling its initGui() method"

Comment: Please edit your post for add more information and context, not in comments. And please add the content of your `metadata.ini` and a list of what you have already done.

Answer (score 4):

You can add it as XYZ tiles very easily.
1. right click XYZ Tiles
2. New Connection
3. connaction url is `https://maps-for-free.com/layer/relief/z{z}/row{y}/{z}_{x}-{y}.jpg`
4. click OK.

You can then add it to QGIS from the browser whenever you want.

Instructions with pictures can be found [here](https://bogind.github.io/Arc2QGIS/Basics/import_data.html#xyz)

I would recommend setting the Max Zoom Level to 11 just like in their site.